# Unable to decode byte

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode

So, I am obtaining some xml data. One such example, is as follows:

```
xmlString = '<location>san diego, ça</location>'
```

This is currently as a string. I now need to convert it to a XML object, by using ElementTree, fromstring() method.
The import is as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

The method call is:

```
xml = ET.fromstring(xmlString)
```

I kept on getting errors, saying:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position xxx: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

In order to deal with this I looked quite a bit over StackOverflow, as well as Python Docs.

It seems a suggestion is to encode and decode the string.

```
xmlString = xmlString.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
xmlString = xmlString.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

The ignore is for errors, but they still arise. This is done prior to converting the xmlString into a xml object. But still the error comes up!

Any ideas?

The full code is:

```
xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><o><location>san diego, ça</location>
</o>'
xmlString = xmlString.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
xmlString = xmlString.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
xml = ET.fromstring(xmlString)
```

Using Python 2.7

Comment: Yeah. Share the code and the traceback.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have written a snippet which is usable in the command line

Comment: XML is normally expected to be UTF-8 encoded, `fromstring()` expects you to pass in a *byte string* (not unicode). Trying to re-code UTF-8 as ASCII is not going to work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but even if I remove the decode('ascii', 'ignore') it breaks on encoding the string itself

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Python 2.7 - just edited post adding this info too.

Comment: Then why are you encoding at all? You have a *byte* string, exactly what `ET.fromstring()` wants to have. `str.encode()` will do an implicit *decode* first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `str.encode()`; Python 2 strings are *already* encoded, so Python tries to do the right thing and first **decode** to `unicode` so it can then encode the value back to a bytestring for you.

This implicit decode is done with the default codec, `ASCII`:

```
>>> '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><o><location>san diego, ça</location></o>'.encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 62: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Note that I called `.encode()` but the exception is `UnicodeDecodeError`; Python was **decoding** here first.

However, because `ET.fromstring()` already *wants* UTF-8 encoded bytes, you do not need to recode the value *at all*.

If you see problems with parsing the string value, make sure you saved your Python source code using the right codec, UTF8, from your text editor.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters I appreciate your help. What I have found, is by removing the encode and decode, it does work mostly. However occasionally I do find a char that seems to break it, hence I led myself into encoding and decoding. I think this maybe an issue with ElementTree. For example, I was experiencing issues with Ø, which is a UTF-8 character: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ . However when using multiple elements of  Ø I was unable to using ET.fromString method.

Comment: @redrubia: Where does the XML data *come* from? It could be that there are errors in that data, or the codec is declared incorrectly in the XML header, or other such errors. ElementTree can handle correctly-encoded XML just fine.

Comment: @redrubia: Next, it could also be you are not handling the *output* from ElementTree correctly; you'll get Unicode values, and if you are printing those or writing to a file, you need to ensure that encoding is handled correctly.